# Regular and critical values of a map from the torus to the 2-sphere

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let the 2-sphere be denoted by $S^2$ and $T^2$ be the torus realized as a regular submanifold of $\mathbb{R^3}$ by taking a circle of radius 1 at $(0,2,0)$ in the $yz$-plane and rotating it about the $x$-axis. Let $\gamma:\mathbb{R^3}\to S^2$ be $\gamma(x,y,z)=\frac{(x,y,z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$. Let $g:T^2\to S^2$ be the restriction of $\gamma$ to $T^2$. I want to find the regular and critical values of $\gamma$. I guess this can be done by parametrizing the torus but it seems very tedious. I was wondering if there is any other method. If $\pi:\mathbb{R^3}\to \mathbb{R^2}$ is the projection $\pi(x,y,z)=(y,z)$ and $p:T^2\to\mathbb{R^2}$ the restriction of $\pi$ to $T^2$. Then $\gamma=g\circ p \circ \pi$. Or equivalently, $$g=\gamma \circ \pi^{-1}\circ p^{-1}$$. Now we can find the differential of $g$ and it's kernel will give all the critical points and their image will be all the critical values. I am not too sure how I can take the differential of the compositions and the inversions. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: That composition doesn't make sense, $$ (g \circ p \circ \pi )(x,y,z) = ( g \circ p)(y,z)$$ and now we have to stop since $p(y,z)$ is not well-defined. It is not clear that $y,z$ are the coordinates that you want to use on $T^2$.

Comment: Also, although you may be able to play around with the maps and get a composition equivalent to the map you want, you still will know nothing about how the coordinates relate to each other so you get stuck. You have to take into account that when you write $(x,y,z)$ you are restricting these to $T^2$ and so relations among the variables $x,y,z$ may arise.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to what I wrote above, although "tedious", you should just parametrize $T^2$ in terms of the rectangular coordinates $x,y,z$ or curved-coordinates $u,v$. This actually isn't too hard.

$\bullet$  Consider a circle of $1$ in the $yz$-plane with center $(0,2,0)$

$\bullet$ If you rotate any point on this circle about the $z$ axis then it's distance from the origin doesn't change.

$\bullet$ Hence if $(x,y,z) \in T^2$ then $\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2} - 2\right)^2 + z^2 = 1^2 =1$. In general we would have $\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2} - a\right)^2 + z^2 = r^2$. See if you can figure out which triangle are these lengths corresponding to.

$\bullet$ You can now define a function $f: D \to \mathbb{R}^3$ in which $f$ gives local coordinates for $p \in T^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ i.e $f(u,v) = (u,v,z(u,v))$ where we solve for $z$ above. This is just an example of getting coordinates arising from the graph of a smooth function. In this case we can take $g = \gamma \circ f$.

This is probably the best way to go about the problem. Although we are taking these coordinates from the graph of a function, you can safely use $z = \sqrt{1-\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2\right)^2}$ (or the one with $-$) since the only difference is a sign. This is the $z$ coordinate in the above description of $f$ and so your restriction will look like,

$$(\gamma \circ f)(u,v)= \gamma(u,v,z(u,v))$$

$\bullet$ Another route you can go is to uncover the two-parameter parametrization of the torus. You wish to rotate a circle of radius $1$ with center $(0,2,0)$ about the $z$-axis. Just apply the rotation matrix.

$$\\$$

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} \cos v & - \sin v & 0 \\ \sin v & \ \ \cos v & 0 \\ 0 &\ \  0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}}_{\textrm{rotation about}\  z-axis} \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ R+r \cos u \\ r \sin u \end{pmatrix}}_{\textrm{parametrization of circle we wish to rotate}} = \begin{pmatrix}  (R + r \cos u)(-\sin v) \\ (R + r \cos u)(\cos v) \\ r \sin u \end{pmatrix}$$

$\bullet$ Letting $R = 2$ and $r = 1$, we get the desired parametrization,

$$ \sigma(u,v) = (-(2+ \cos u) \sin v, (2+ \cos u) \cos v, \sin u)$$

Hence you can take $g=\gamma \circ \sigma$.